# MySQL read replicas with lower specs?

Tags: mysql, replication

I was wondering, is it generally considered safe to have MySQL read-replicas with lower specs than the primary read/write instance?

... I'm assuming yes, since the main box has to deal with more than just the read-replicas processing the binary logs? But, I wasn't sure about best practices considering all of the factors.

If anyone has any thoughts to share, would be appreciated.